# How to use an extension method to make an interface complete

Tags: c#, inheritance, extension-methods

Given an interface IFoo

```
interface IFoo {
    void Do();
    void Stuff();
}
```

Let assume there are (legacy) classes Foo1, Foo2, Foo3 all implementing IFoo.

Stuff can be done by using some methods of IFoo, or in case of the newer classes, by just using DoStuff(). Actually, one might look at it as if DoStuff() was "forgotten" on IFoo.

There are also newer Classes FooX (FooY, ...) implementing IFoo2, in additional those has a method DoStuff();

```
 interface IFoo2 : IFoo {
        void DoStuff();
   }
```

I need to accept IFoo objects, and be able to "Do Stuff" on it.

```
 //Let us assume foos = new IFoo[] {new Foo1(), new Foo2(), new Foo3(), new FooX()};

 void MyMethod(IFoo[] foos){
     foreach(foo in foos){
        //DoStuff is not defined in IFoo
        foo.DoStuff();
     }
 }
```

So, I thought to just define an extension method DoStuff() on IFoo for the legacy classes

```
public static DoStuff(this IFoo self){
    self.Do();
    self.Stuff();
}
```

Unfortunately, this extension method is always called, even for FooX.

I Could do something like

```
public static DoSomeStuff(this IFoo self){
    if(self is IFoo2) {
        (self as IFoo2).DoStuff()
    } else {
       self.Do();
       self.Stuff();
    }
}

void MyMethod(IFoo[] foos){
     foreach(foo in foos){            
        foo.DoSomeStuff();
     }
 }
```

However, the method MyMethod reside in a legacy project, currently not yet aware of IFoo2. Is it possible to find a solution without using IFoo2?

Comment: `Unfortunately, this extension method is always called, even for FooX.` Why is that a problem?

Comment: because DoStuff() in the newer classes is not necessary implemented as Do(); Stuff();

Comment: Then it's not semantically extending `IFoo`, and should not extend it, nor should you be passing it to a method that expects an `IFoo` instance, since it's not capable of providing that contract.

Comment: while its kinda interesting problem but I cant see how it would be like in real world example(?!)

Comment: What's wrong with implementing Do(); and Stuff(); in the newer classes, and having those functions do nothing?

Comment: it would be better if  `IFoo` implements `IFoo2` instead... so classes can implement `IFoo2` to do `DoStuff` or implement `IFoo` do to more specific thing with `Do` and `Stuff` (while having DoStuff too which basically calls `Do` then `Stuff`)

Comment: @Servy this is the same usecase as if DoStuff has been overriden in a derived class. Do(); Stuff(); is just a base implementation. If IFoo would have DoStuff() then the most specialized implementation would heve been called.

Comment: @StijnVanAntwerpen Again, if `Foo3` isn't actually properly implementing `Do` and `Stuff`, then it shouldn't be implementing `IFoo`, and you shouldn't be passing it to methods expecting an `IFoo`, because apparently it doesn't fulfill that contract.  If an `IFoo2` object cannot be treated as an `IFoo` object, then `IFoo2` shouldn't extend `IFoo`.  It's purporting to fulfill a contract it doesn't actually fulfill.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Well, I used a real life problem and narrowed it down to a theoretical question eliminating all the stuff that would complicate the question. (I actually want to make abstraction of the use of the extension method by overriding it in a mock object)

Comment: @Servy: It is: FooX does implement Do() and Stuff() correctly. However, it does also implement DoStuff() as Do(); SomeOther(); Stuff(). Which is perfectly fine.

Comment: @StijnVanAntwerpen So if it implements `Do` and `Stuff` correctly, and `MyMethod` will work correctly when given a method that implements `Do` and `Stuff` correctly, then it should function when given a `Foo3` object and calls `Do` and `Stuff` on it, and you have no problem.

Comment: @Servy True, however SomeOther() would not be called, although you could argue it shouldn't. So: move on to FooY :-) FooY does a heavy calculation in both Do() and Stuff(). In DoStuff() it does it only once.

Comment: well you could use reflection but that would be pretty horrible. The whole situation is a mess. If an `IFoo2` is not behaving nice when calling `Do` and `Stuff` and *needs* `DoStuff` called, then it has no business implementing `IFoo`

Comment: @StijnVanAntwerpen Then have it cache the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your variable has the type `IFoo`, the extension method `DoStuff` will be called. The usual way of solving this is exactly what you propose in your last paragraph, or ensuring that you use `IFoo2` instead of `IFoo` in places where you want the newer interface method to be called.

Comment: All other suggestions are worse, so the only acceptable answer is that it can not be done.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't extend `IFoo` interface, like that. It's break [Interface Segregation principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle).

If these object represents exactly the same entity in your code you shouldn't use different interfaces for them.
You might create extension method if you want extend functionality of classes which implements interface `IFoo`, but don't create second interface which represents the same contract. However if you want to change `IFoo` contract - refactor legacy objects (add missing implementation).

Comment: True, but even if IFoo2 did not inherent IFoo, but instead FooX would implement IFoo and IFoo2, the problem would be approximately the same.

Comment: If your DoStuff() method should do, like you said above: "Do(); SomeOther(); Stuff();" what's the problem to extend your IFoo interface for this additional method? In the worse case it will just call for legacy objects: "Do(); Stuff()" and it will be much better than extending IFoo interface.

Comment: I don't own IFoo and can't add a method to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an abstract subclass that implements the methods Do and Stuff for the classes that at the current time don't implement it.

```
public abstract class abstractFoo : IFoo 
{
    public virtual void Do() {}
    public virtual void Stuff(){}
}
```

If you can then inherit from this abstract class

```
public class Foo: IFoo 
{
    // interface implementation required
}

becomes:

public class Foo: abstractFoo
{
    // interface implementation NOT required
}
```

Comment: How does this improve anything?  It just breaks tons and tons of code (that's all dependant on the interface) and adds nothing.

Comment: I think it would work in the given example. But you are right, it could break a lot of dependencies. I guess I'm trying to show a solution that could work if you didn't have a lot of legacy code holding you back, and you could still redesign a few things

Comment: *How* would it work in the given example?  What does this accomplish that the interface doesn't?  It *removes* functionality of using an interface, it doesn't add to it.  That combined with the fact that, given the description of the problem, it's a change that could never possibly made even if it *did* work (which it doesn't) because the solution is a legacy app that wouldn't be able to have such a breaking change.

Comment: using an abstract class allows for the use of virtual methods, something you can't do with an interface. It means that any class that inherits from the abstract class already has the virtual functions available.

Comment: Having an interface already gives you the same functionality.  Any derived type can *always* re-implement an interface, re-binding the methods to be called when the interface methods are called, not that that's even a problem in the first place here.  So this not only could never possibly be implemented, doesn't solve the described problem, but also isn't something that an interface couldn't do.

Comment: @Servy This breaks the principal of an interface completely. One major stand out is that you cant have multiple base classes - but an interface is supposed to provide a service not template it.

Comment: @MichaelCoxon What?  An interface is a contract that says that all objects implementing the interface contain all of the indicated members.  It doesn't provide a service.  Why do you think an abstract class would be preferable here?  What is is accomplishing?  It's not solving the technical problem, and it's not the appropriate conceptual tool for the situation either.

Comment: @Servy I argued my point with the wrong user here lol... my bad

Answer (score 0):

IMHO `FooX` shouldn't be implementing `IFoo` to begin with and some reconsideration should be made of your current arquitecture.

That said, and not knowing exactly what limitations you are fighting against, could you send the `IFooX`s through a wrapper? Something like the following:

```
public class FooXWrapper<T>: IFoo where T: FooX
{
    readonly T foo;
    bool doCalled;

    public FooWrapper(T foo)
    {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    public void Do()
    {
        doCalled = true;
    }

    public void Stuff()
    {
         if (!doCalled)
             throw new InvalidOperationException("Must call Do");

         foo.DoStuff();
    }
}
```

Its an ugly hack, but given the circumstances...